# Inline button for telegram bot is unresponsive

Tags: telegram-bot

```
var token = "<insert token here>";
var telegramUrl = "https://api.telegram.org/bot" + token;
var webAppUrl = "<insert url here>";
function setWebhook() {
var url = telegramUrl + "/setWebhook?url=" + webAppUrl;
var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);
}
function sendMessage(chat_id, text) {
var url = telegramUrl + "/sendMessage?chat_id=" + chat_id + "&text="+ text;
var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);
Logger.log(response.getContentText());
}
function sendKeyboard(chatId, text, keyboard) {
var data = {
method: "post",
payload: {
method: "sendMessage",
chat_id: String(chatId),
text: text,
parse_mode: "HTML",
reply_markup: JSON.stringify(keyboard)
}
  };
UrlFetchApp.fetch('https://api.telegram.org/bot' + token + '/', data);
}
var spenderKeyBoard = {
"inline_keyboard":[
[{
"text":"Adam",
"callback_data":"Adam"
}],
[{
"text":"Mutual",
"callback_data":"Mutual"
}],
[{
"text":"Juniper",
"callback_data":"Juniper"
}]
  ]
}
var keyBoardSwitch = "Start";
function doPost(e) {
var contents = JSON.parse(e.postData.contents);
var chat_id = contents.message.from.id;
var botAcknowledge = "expense updated";
var first_name = contents.message.from.first_name;
var ssId = "<insert ssID here>";
var expenseSheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(ssId).getSheetByName("Master Ledger")
var nowDate = new Date();
var nowDate = Utilities.formatDate(nowDate, 'Europe/Berlin', "YYYY/MM/DD");
var lr = expenseSheet.getLastRow();
var idRow = lr - 24
var actualRow = expenseSheet.getLastRow() + 1
sendMessage(chat_id, "Start")
if(contents.message && contents.message.text != "/start" && contents.message.text.length > 4){
var chat_id = contents.message.from.id;
var text = contents.message.text;
var item = text.split(",");
expenseSheet.appendRow([idRow, nowDate, item[0].substring(5), item[1], item[2], item[3], item[4], item[5]]);
expenseSheet.getRange(lr, 4).copyFormatToRange(0, 4, 4, actualRow, actualRow);
return sendMessage(chat_id, botAcknowledge);
  }
else if(contents.message && contents.message.text == "/exp"){
return sendKeyboard(chat_id, "Enter", spenderKeyBoard);
  }
else if(contents.callback_query) {
var chat_id = contents.callback_query.from.id;
var data = contents.callback_query.data;
return sendMessage(chat_id, "confirm button is working");
  }
}
```

I have a bot set-up using Google Apps Script but for some reason I can't get the inline buttons to work. When I click the inline buttons from the bot, the button simply flashes for a few seconds then nothing happens. It responds to text inputs from users just fine though. Code below:

I will actually code in my workflow for the inline buttons, but at this point, the bot does not seem to be able to receive the callback_query from an inline button input.

Used multiple variations of the inline keyboard code from other bots I've found online but still could not get it to work. The inline keyboard does pop up in my bot, but after clicking any button, the button flashes for a few seconds and nothing happens.